# Linux web console for multiple machine

Tags: linux, shell, console

I'm looking for a web-based tool allowing me to do the following:

- Have a single web-based UI for multiple servers
- Services monitoring: for each server I want to see all running daemons and be able to start/stop/restart them (just like windows services)
- Have a interactive web-based shell allowing to execute commands to multiple machines directly from my browser
- Fast scripting: be able to create scripts directly in my browser and run and deploy them to all my machines

Do you know if there is something similar around ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some commercial web interfaces for managing linux servers.
[cPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/) and [DirectAdmin](http://www.directadmin.com/) are the most popular examples.

You can have a shell in the browser using something like [Gate One](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne) ([video demo](http://vimeo.com/24857127)).

There is also [Zentyal](http://www.zentyal.org/), a linux distribution that was designed to be administered through a web-interface.

Answer (score 1):

There's some commercial offerings which try to deliver this (Tivoli, unicenter TNG, Openview, BMC) IME, they mostly deliver this by being a jack of all trades rather than a master of one.

> Services monitoring: for each server I want to see all running daemons and be able to start/stop/restart them (just like windows services)

Nagios, Munin, Cacti

> Have a interactive web-based shell allowing to execute commands to multiple machines directly from my browser

Canonical Landscape, and while it's not web-based (how 'interactive' should system admin be?) there's clusterssh

> Fast scripting: be able to create scripts directly in my browser and run and deploy them to all my machines

Isn't that the same as the previous requirement?

Answer (score 0):

There's [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/), but personally I don't fancy the way it does things. Your mileage may wary.

Comment: Yes, I know Webmin but it is more for management and configuration. I would like something for daily management.